# Setting default values in wtforms form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am developing "add member details" and "edit member details" page. For "add member details" I am using wtf form shown below ( Stripped version )

```
class RegisterForm(Form):

    name = TextField(
        'Name', 
        validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)]
    )

    phone = TextField(
        'Phone', 
        validators=[DataRequired(),
            Length(min=10, max=10, message="Invalid phone number")],
    )
```

For edit page, idea is to inherit EditForm from RegisterForm and set default to values of name and phone. But struggling to manage inheritance. Below is what i am trying to achieve. Any help is appreciated.

```
class EditForm(RegisterForm):
    def __init__( not sure of args, member ):
        self.name.default = member.name
        self.phone.default = member.phone
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `TextField` you should set `self.field.data` instead of `self.field.default`. And in this case you can accomplish your default values simply by passing the `member` in the default constructor of your form using the `obj` keyword. Here's what I mean:

```
form = EditForm(obj=member)
```

The form will search for attributes on `member` to fill its fields with the same name (here's [the docs](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#the-form-class) about it). It has the same effect as following code:

```
class EditForm(RegisterForm):
    def __init__(self, member, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name.data = member.name
        self.phone.date = member.phone
```